# Magento2: how to get guest informations in checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout

Please, how to get **guest** **informations** like **email, address, phone** ... in **checkout**?

Comment: The Magento stores this additional details for guest customer, only then customer fill this items on the checkout step and they will be stored in quote. You can't get this details before guest customer fill them.

Comment: Mind to add this as an answer @jonijones?!

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, if it will be helpful, I can create answer with more details.

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution, you can get guest and customer informations in checkout , inject `Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote` on your view method.

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    ],
    function ($,Component,quote,placeOrderAction) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            defaults: {
                template: 'Path/to/your/template'
            },

            getEmail: function () {
                if(quote.guestEmail) return quote.guestEmail;
                else return window.checkoutConfig.customerData.email;
            },

            getLastName: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().lastname;
            },

            getFirstName: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().firstname;
            },

            getAddress: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().street[0]+", "+quote.billingAddress().postcode+" "+quote.billingAddress().city+", Maroc";
            },

            getPhone: function () {
                return quote.billingAddress().telephone;
            },

        });
    }
);
```

Comment: it says `quote.shippingAddress() is null`